# Is it true that Russian adjectives always denote a constant quality while participles, temporary?

Tags: прилагательные

It is indeed true that distinguishing between Russian adjectives and participles can be very hard. E.g. "жареный картофель" — an adjective; "жаренный с грибами картофель" — a participle.

My question is: is it true that adjectives denote something constant, and participles, something temporary?

Let me explain myself.

> Прилагательные обозначают постоянные признаки, а причастия — признаки,
> изменяющиеся во времени. Пример. "Плавучий маяк" — постоянный признак
> (расположенный на воде), это прилагательное. "Плавающий человек" —
> признак, изменяющийся во времени (тот, кто плавает сейчас), это
> причастие.

[https://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/7-klass/morfologiia-prichastie-10509/razlichenie-prichastii-i-imen-prilagatelnykh-7286607/re-4f26bcf7-6925-46d1-9043-4f11df9b105e#:~:text=Прилагательные%20обозначают%20постоянные%20признаки%2C%20а,плавает%20сейчас](https://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/7-klass/morfologiia-prichastie-10509/razlichenie-prichastii-i-imen-prilagatelnykh-7286607/re-4f26bcf7-6925-46d1-9043-4f11df9b105e#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%B0,%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81))

Also compare: горячий — горящий, висячий — висящий...

This is something that got cemented in my brain. We were always taught this theory in school.
But is it completely true?

I would argue:

> Зелёный помидор когда-нибудь покраснеет.
>
> Маленькая девочка вырастет и станет большой.
>
> Больной человек вполне может выздороветь.
>
> Грязную посуду можно вымыть.

And so on.
That is, I disagree that an adjective denotes a constant quality of an object or a person.

Who's right — the linguists or me? (Прилагательное обозначает постоянный признак, как учат лингвисты, или это ложь?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Прилагательные обозначают постоянные признаки, а причастия — признаки, изменяющиеся во времени. Пример. "Плавучий маяк" — постоянный признак (расположенный на воде), это прилагательное. "Плавающий человек" — признак, изменяющийся во времени (тот, кто плавает сейчас), это причастие.

I guess this was an attempt to capture the difference between these two particular paradigms of verb forms ending in *-чий* and *-щий*, the former producing adjectives and the latter — present active participles.

Historically, both these paradigms were used to form participles — the former in Old Russian, the latter in Church Slavonic.

All participles (as a grammatical concept) had almost fallen out of use in speech by the beginning of the XVIII century, replaced by analytical constructs: *крадущийся волк > волк, который крадётся* etc. However, later on, in the XIX century, they experienced a revival of sorts, probably influenced by French.

Here's what happened up to that point:

1. Old Russian participles were repurposed as other parts of speech.

   Here's their declension table for the short first person singular:

   | Case | M | F |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | Nom | несa, видя | несучи, видячи |
   | Acc | несучь, видячь | несучу, видячу |
   | Gen | несуча, видяча | несучъ, видячъ |
   | Dat | несучу, видячу | несучи, видячи |
   | Inst | несучемь, видячемь | несучею, видячею |
   | Loc | несучи, видячи | несучи, видячи |

   (Gorhskova, Khaburgaev, *Историческая грамматика русского языка*)

   1. The nominative forms have been repurposed as adverbial participles (*деепричастия*): *я живу, неся свой крест* (= *я живу, несущий свой крест*); *я иду крадучись* (= *я иду, крадущаяся*). As originally nominative forms, adverbial participles can only describe actions of subjects in the nominative (although in the modern language, they technically modify the verb of the predicate).
   2. A relatively small number of oblique forms (around 30 or so) have been repurposed as adjectives expressing an intrinsic ability or inclination to do something:

      - *висячий* "able to hang; designed to be hanging": *висячий замок* "padlock", literally "hanging lock"; *висячие сады Семирамиды* "Hanging Gardens of Semiramis"
      - *колючий* "able to prick"
      - *гремучий* "able to produce loud sounds": *гремучий студень* "blasting jelly", *гремучая змея* "rattlesnake"

      All these adjectives started out as participles that would be *висящий, колющий, гремящий* in the modern language. Some of them have completely diverged in meaning from the original words: *горячий, дремучий*.
2. Church Slavonic participles, primarily only used to give otherwise Russian discourse the [grand style](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85), made a comeback and became Russian participles in their own right. They express the same thing as their analytical counterparts express: *смеющийся человек / человек, который смеётся*.

> My question is: is it true that adjectives denote something constant, and participles, something temporary?

No, that's not universally true.

Participles are formed *regularly* from verbs and define the property of being an agent or a patient of the action expressed by this verb. *Regularly* is the crux here: participles are verb forms just like any other form, and all (or most) verbs are able to form them — even newly coined, borrowed or made up verbs. If we accept [*будлануть* and *курдячить*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glokaya_kuzdra) as verbs, we must automatically accept *будланувшая* and *курдячащая* as their participles.

Adjectives are nominals (noun-like words) that define or modify nouns. Of course, all of them have their etymologies, and some of them are indeed derived from what used to be a participle in the past, but it's not a regular pattern anymore. You can try to form adjectives like ***стрелючий* ("able to shoot") or ***программучий* ("able to program") in modern-day Russian, but they would be taken to be clearly humorous novelty words, at most.

This distinction that you're mentioning is only relevant for parallel forms in *-чий* and *-щий*, of which there are perhaps only several dozen that have survived to this day.

Comment: @Cocopop: I was trying to say that using Church Slavonic was a way to give a discourse, otherwise Russian, the [grand style](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Учение_о_трёх_стилях) (_высокий штиль_)

Answer (score 4):

(1)  You have correctly pointed out an inaccuracy in the statement that an adjective denotes a constant quality.  IMHO, one slight amendment would mend that rule:
an adjective denotes a constant or *lasting* quality.

(2)  Participles do not necessarily denote a temporary quality.
This can be gleaned from counterexamples:
'[плавающий фундамент](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_raft_system)', '[пикирyющий бомбардировщик](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dive_bomber)', '[удушающий приём](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chokehold)'.

(It can certainly be argued that on such occasions, participles are playing an adjectival role. Nonetheless, technically, they remain participles.)